# Yarn auto Bump version

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, yarnpkg

I am using 4 digit version in package.json like "version": "1.3.0-0".
when I run the command yarn version --prerelease on windows I get following response. which is correct.

```
info Current version: 1.3.0-0
info New version: 1.3.0-1
```

But when I do the same in Jenkins, I only see this in logs.

```
 + yarn version --prerelease

[2020-07-02T17:36:32.215Z] yarn version v1.12.3

[2020-07-02T17:36:32.215Z] info Current version: 1.3.0-0

[2020-07-02T17:36:32.215Z] Done in 0.04s.
```

It does not bump the version. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Are the versions of yarn the same?

Comment: Sorry, I just realised the same. Older version of yarn doesn't have this.

Answer (score 0):

Yarn v1.12.3 don't support --prerelease. Updating the version to yarn-1.21.1 fixed the issue.